# Swift: Toolchain download seemingly components missing

Tags: linux, swift, llvm, swift-package-manager

On the swift website you have several options / versions to choose from, but some of the packages don't seem to include **swift-build**, what is the reason for this?

Notably:

[Swift-2.2.1 14.04 May 3](https://swift.org/builds/swift-2.2.1-release/ubuntu1404/swift-2.2.1-RELEASE/swift-2.2.1-RELEASE-ubuntu14.04.tar.gz)

Should be similar for the version of 15.10. It does not seem to be the case with the master-branch tar-balls.

Its actually quite relevant for me to try to stay up to date as possible, since Swift reaks of memory leaks at this point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release of Swift 2.2 does not include the swift package manager, as the package manager was still too early in development to include in a release version of Swift at that point. Instead, a feature was added to the package manager to allow using the version from a 3.0 toolchain with the Swift from a 2.2 toolchain, so that people could use a more recent version of the package manager.